# Custom Screen Saver Raspberry Pi Bulls Eye

Tags: screen-saver

Has anyone come come across an updated tutorial on setting up a custom screensaver for the raspberry pi bulls eye?
The current ones I have come across use omxplayer which is no longer supported.
[Raspberry Pi: Use a Video as a Screensaver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKSmJfTewG4)
[Screensaver on the Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-screensaver/)
It appears VLC is what is recommended [Custom screensaver](https://www.reddit.com/r/RASPBERRY_PI_PROJECTS/comments/10pbk7j/custom_screensaver/) Just not sure how to use VLC with an mp4 as a screensaver